# VirtualMachine logs into VPN, share connection with host

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

My customer's VPN will only work on IE6 32bit. So I got a Windows XP 32bit VM installed and got the VM to connect into the VPN.

I would now like to share VPN connection with the host (Windows 7 64bit).

How do I go about it?

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 1):

Add a second network card to your windows xp virtual machine that will be connected to a host-only network. Then use the methods of Internet Connection Sharing as described, for example, in the following article:
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/expert/crawford_02july01.mspx